# How to create a point in time architecture in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I read [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/database-design-a-point-in-time-architecture/) article on building a point in time architecture for your database. It looks to me as an elegant solution, but the article is allready from some time ago (2007). I was wondering:
1. Are there any other methods to solve this?
2. What are the pro's and con's of this and other methods?
3. Is there a mysql implementation available for these methods that I can re-use?

Comment: It would be good, if you don't force us to read 2km long articles just to understand what is your question about ;) Summarize that article in several sentences in the beginning of your question, please... ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just skimmed the article, but it looks like the author's reinventing the [bi-temporal database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database) wheel. I'm not confident he did a good job of it, but I didn't read it closely.

Before you get too deep into this, take some time to skim Richard Snodgrass's old book *Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL*. It's available as a PDF from [his web page](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html).

I think MySQL's lack of support for CHECK constraints and peculiar implementation of GROUP BY will make his approach hard to implement.  If you have freedom of choice, PostgreSQL might be a better platform for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a 528 page book! That will get me through the weekend. :-)

Comment: @MartijnBurger: Kind of suggests that article might have missed a point or two, eh?

Comment: I was hoping there would be some standard implementation for these kind of chalenges, without needing all the background knowledge.